# Parent 'this' refers to child props in function after it was binded in constructor?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I have run into a weird situation that I'm not sure why it's exactly happening. 
In function onPortfolioHeatChange on first piece of code, "this" refers to child props so I can access child props by only typing this.propName. I want it to refer to this of the parent which is why I have `this.onPortfolioHeatChange = this.onPortfolioHeatChange.bind(this);` in the constructor, Here is the parent code:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import * as indicesActions from '../actions/indicesActions';
import * as sliderActions from '../actions/sliderActions';
import SliderSection from './SliderSection';

class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
      super(props, context);

      this.onPortfolioHeatChange = this.onPortfolioHeatChange.bind(this);
  }

  onPortfolioHeatChange(sliderValues) {
    this.props.actions.sliders.recalculatePortFolioSuccessAPI(
      {
        heat: sliderValues[0][0],
        weights: sliderValues.filter((val, ind) => ind !== 0).map((val, ind) => val[0]),
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <Child
          data={this.props.data}
          onSlidersChange={this.onPortfolioHeatChange}
        />
    );
  }
}

Home.propTypes ={
  indices: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  data: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  loading: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  actions: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};


function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  return {
    indices: state.indices,
    data: state.data,
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: {
      indices: bindActionCreators(indicesActions, dispatch),
      sliders: bindActionCreators(sliderActions, dispatch),
    }
  };
}
```

This is the child and it has a call to this.props.onSlidersChange in the function onDragStop. onDragStop is passed to grandchild. I didn't include markup because I don't think it's relevant here.

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import grandChild from './common/grandChild';


class Child extends Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
      super(props, context);

      this.state = {
          sliderValues: [[100, true]],
      }

      this.onDragStop = this.onDragStop.bind(this);
    }

    onDragStop() {
        this.props.onSlidersChange(this.state.sliderValues);
    }

  render() {
    return (
        // some jsx grandchild
    );
  }
}

Child.propTypes = {
    data: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    onSlidersChange: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
}

export default Child;
```

This is the grandchild which takes onDragStop from the child and adds it to the Slider.

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';

class Grandchild extends React.Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Slider
                onDragStop={this.props.onDragStop}
            />
        );
    };
}

Grandchild.propTypes = { 
  onDragStop: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

export default Grandchild;
```

Comment: Since you have `this.onPortfolioHeatChange = this.onPortfolioHeatChange.bind(this);`, `this` inside `onPortfolioHeatChange` will refer to the instance of `Home`.

Comment: Why there is a downvote?

Answer (score 0):

Given how react does autobinding when you write a component using ES6, you may have to do the binding explicitly in your event handler configuration. Notice the .bind(this) for onSliderChange property. Here's the relevant doc for this: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#no-autobinding

```
  render() {
    return (
        <Child
          data={this.props.data}
          onSlidersChange={this.onPortfolioHeatChange.bind(this)}
        />
    );
```

Would be good to know if this solves your problem.

Comment: OP already does `this.onPortfolioHeatChange = this.onPortfolioHeatChange.bind(this);` in the constructor.

Comment: @FelixKling True, thanks for the catch. I re-read the article and it in fact says that it's better to do this in the constructor for performance reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured out the problem. It seems hot reloading didn't update the file while I was debugging so the binding of this in the constructor didn't take effect even though I re-ran the app multiple times. I also forgot to add the slider reducer to the combine reducers which shouldn't be related at all but it might have helped.